# Solidity - Return Array from function

Tags: solidity

This code will succesfully find the owner of any contract after I supply the contract and ID. How can I make this into a search function which finds 10 or 100 different id's?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

interface INft {
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address); //works
}

contract Test {
    function getNftTokenOwner(address _nft) external view returns (address){
//        return INft(_nft).ownerOf(_tokenId);
    return INft(_nft).ownerOf(0);
    }
    


//    function getNftTokenOwner(address _nft, uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address){
//        return INft(_nft).ownerOf(_tokenId);
//    return INft(_nft).ownerOf(0);
//    }


}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to get ALL the wallet addresses from the current owner of token ID [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] in one list and not having to create 10 different functions in order to do this

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over it and save the addresses to an array like this.

```
function getNftTokenHolder(address _nft, unit _tokenIds) public returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory addr = new address[](_tokenIds);
    for (uint i; i < _tokenIds; i++) {
        addr[i] = INft(_nft).ownerOf(i);
    }

}
```

This should work. It will return an array with all addresses. Just insert how many tokenIds you want to loop over.